# OpenGL: alpha-to-coverage cross-fade

Tags: opengl, shader, alpha

If using alpha-to-coverage without explicitly setting the samples from the shader (a hardware 4.x feature?), is the coverage mask for alpha value ‘a‘ then guaranteed to be the bit-flip of the coverage mask for alpha value ‘1.f-a‘?

Or in other words: if i render two objects in the same location, and the pixel alphas of the two objects sum up to 1.0, is it then guaranteed that all samples of the pixel get written to (assuming both objects fully cover the pixel)?

The reason why I ask is that I want to crossfade two objects and during the crossfade each object should still properly depth-sort in respect to itself (without interacting with the depth values of the other object and without becoming ‚see-through‘).

If not, how can I realize such a ‚perfect‘ crossfade in a single render pass?

Answer (score 3):

The logic for alpha-to-coverage computation is required to have the same invariance and proportionality guarantees as `GL_SAMPLE_COVERAGE` (which allows you to specify a floating-point coverage value applied to all fragments in a given rendering command).

However, said guarantees are not exactly specific:

> It is intended that the number of 1’s in this value be proportional to the sample coverage value, with all 1’s corresponding to a value of 1.0 and all 0’s corresponding to 0.0.

Note the use of the word "intended" rather than "required". The spec is deliberately super-fuzzy on all of this.

Even the invariance is really fuzzy:

> The algorithm can and probably should be different at different pixel locations. If it does differ, it should be defined relative to window, not screen, coordinates, so that rendering results are invariant with respect to window position.

Again, note the word "should". There are no actual requirements here.

So basically, the answer to all of your questions are "the OpenGL specification provides no guarantees for that".

---

That being said, the general thrust of your question suggests that you're trying to (ab)use multisampling to do cross-fading between two overlapping things without having to do a render-to-texture operation. That's just not going to work well, even if the standard actually guaranteed something about the alpha-to-coverage behavior.

Basically, what you're trying to do is multisample-based dither-based transparency. But like with standard dithering methods, the quality is based entirely on the number of samples. A 16x multisample buffer (which is a *huge* amount of multisampling) would only give you an effective 16 levels of cross-fade. This would make any kind of animated fading effect not smooth at all.

And the *cost* of doing 16x multisampling is going to be substantially greater than the cost of doing render-to-texture cross-fading. Both in terms of rendering time and memory overhead (16x multisample buffers are gigantic).

---

> If not, how can I realize such a ‚perfect‘ crossfade in a single render pass?

You can't; not in the general case. Rasterizers accumulate values, with new pixels doing math against the accumulated value of all of the prior values. You want to have an operation do math against a specific previous operation, then combine those results and blend against the rest of the previous operations.

That's simply not the kind of math a rasterizer does.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation (as always)! But isn‘t glSampleCoverage https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glSampleCoverage.xml exactly meant for that? The doc even mentions „smooth transitions between renderings of same object“. Is this behaviour (with the invert functionality) somehow accessiblw from shader? I guess when I use a small noise texture to offset the alpha change at each pixel a bit i should get a smooth (albeit noisy) transition and since I‘m forced to use alpha to coverage anyway, I thought i could use MSAA also for the crossfade

Comment: @user1282931: As previously stated, the alpha-to-coverage behavior is computationally equivalent to the sample coverage setting (less the `invert` functionality). In any case, if you need more control over the sample mask, [GL 4.x gives FS's the ability to write a sample mask](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Other_outputs).

Comment: So without GL 4.x there‘s no way to invert the (alpha- or custom sample-) coverage mask on a per pixel basis?